# Unable to set "#" in BaseUrl in the onPrepare function

Tags: protractor

I am trying to dynamically set the `baseUrl` in the `onPrepare` function of **Protractor configuration**. It do sets the URL but doesn't takes hash("#") in context while visiting a page.

```
exports.config: {
     framework: 'jasmine2',
     .
     .
     .
     onPrepare: function() {
          browser.baseUrl = "https://google.com/#2/resource";
     } 
}
```

In above case it runs the tests against `https://google.com` instead of `https://google.com/#2/resource`

Comment: why would you want to enter #2 in url?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the --baseUrl="https://google.com/#2/resource" from the command line:

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --baseUrl="https://google.com/#2/resource"
```

Comment: The use-case here is that I create some data in onPrepare and then make the tests run on it. This is the reason I can't use the command line version.